# IT IS POSSIBLE TO GENERATE SSL CERTIFICATE IF MY URL IS LIKE https://mindset.ccgeo.info:84

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using Lets Encrypt Certbot to generate ssl certificate btw if you notice  my url already have `https`, I only generated it manually and that's not secured. Just want to know if my url is acceptable to have a ssl certificate.

Comment: The certificate is not for the URL, it's for the domain `mindset.ccgeo.info`. You can use it with any protocol on any port, including port 84.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an SSL certificate for any website. You just have to verify ownership of your domain and once the certificate has been issued to you upload it to your website host.